# Problem cloning git remote repository in LAN network

Tags: git, mingw-w64

My colleague has Windows 7 and I have Windows 10. We have both tried to clone from remote LAN repository using MINGW64. My colleague succeeded but something seems to be wrong when I'm doing it. I get the following error from MINGW64:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Suspect you're copying and pasting that command from somewhere and getting some sort of invisible character before the 'g' in 'git'. Try typing it manually, or first pasting into Notepad (or equivalent) to remove undesirable characters, then copying again and pasting into your terminal.

Comment: Thanks @DaveyDaveDave! That actually worked!

Comment: Be *very* careful copy/pasting commands into your shell. See the example at https://thejh.net/misc/website-terminal-copy-paste

Comment: The clue, for your future reference was there in the error message. "command not found" is pretty self explanatory - it's saying that the thing you're trying to do isn't recognised. So you look back at what your shell thinks it's trying to do, and it says "\302\226git", where you think you just put in "git", so there's something appearing before the "g".